# Getting a long line of text to actually break on a % based div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get it so that if a long string of characters are entered in the forums on my new site, it doesn't break the % based div/table for the content.

[This is what I mean](http://codepen.io/POC0bob/pen/PzGPrM)

What am I doing wrong? How do I make it so that it strictly breaks the long character, to fit the area no matter what. I even tried using php code, however it didn't much work as I wanted it to:

```
 <?php echo wordwrap($Body),150,"\n",true); ?>
```

Any ideas, I made that codepen link myself with an example of what happens, and how I want it to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add some CSS:

```
.innerdiv{
  width: 100%; 
  word-wrap: break-word;
  word-break: break-word;
  hyphens: auto;

}
```

Adding the `word-break:` and `hyphens:` properties will force the long word to break rather than extending it's container.

[jsFiddle demo.](https://jsfiddle.net/NotInUse/4fs8eu5f/)

Comment: Ah, I forgot about word-break. This solved my issue, ill mark as correct as soon as it allows me!